# Hierarchical generated tree code on insert

Tags: oracle, join, tree, hierarchical-data

https://i.stack.imgur.com/weX9W.jpg

On every insert in my table, i want to generate this code (1, 1.1, 1.2 ...) based on code from parent of object i am inserting.

My approach is something like this:
- make some SQL function that will generate this code somehow, and she will be called via trigger on every insert in my table.

Had some hard time with string parsing, so what do you think that will be best solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just find parent object, let's say it's code is 1.3 and then count siblings rows with same parent, let's say that you found 2 brothers. 
So your new code value is 1.3.3. But this method demands selecting from same table on which your trigger works. 
And this may cause "ORA-04091: table name is mutating, trigger/function may not see it" when you insert several rows at time. 
There are [workarounds](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_avoiding_mutating_table_error.htm) to avoid this.

Another way is to use view based on this query, instead of trigger:

```
select id, pid, ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(rn, '.'),'.') code
  from (
    select id, pid, 
           row_number() over (partition by level, pid order by seq) rn
      from data connect by pid = prior id
      start with pid is null )
  connect by pid = prior id
  start with pid is null
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0cdd1/2)</sup>

It demands that your table contains column `seq` allowing proper ordering of rows.